# Purpose of Service Discovery such as Eureka

Tags: java, microservices, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I don’t understand the reasoning behind service discovery tools. I understand they are used so micro services can connect but why can’t we just store all the urls/load balancers in the config server as properties? Looking for some explanation for eureka over property file with the micro service urls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Discovery service such as `Eureka` is used for registry purpose so that client can get the address from the registry prior to making a call to the service so if your architecture fits the model where a client based load balancer is favored, Eureka can be a best fit for that. It's norm in microservices that each service can have multiple instances running at a moment for handling the load.

> why can’t we just store all the urls in the config server as
> properties?

If you put the address of the services in the property file of `config server`, how you'll register the address of another instance of the same service at run time and make a call to it. For scalability purpose you need to run more than one instance of service, so it is necessary to have discovery service where ***varying number (1...N)*** of instances of individual service get them registered and make themselves available to the clients with the help of discovery service. Of course, you've to use some orchestration service such as `Kubernetes` to handle how many instances you want to run for the service.

Comment: But if the load balancer url is saved in the config server (http://imtheloadBalancer.com). Then why would a service need to register anything if it’s just invoking the other services  load balancer which will then in turn find the instances

Answer (score 0):

In your example of putting a URL into a config, clients still needs to do discovery to find other micro services . In this case DNS is acting like a discovery service by converting URLs into IP Addresses (to the load balancer).

using a load balancer as state is "server side load balancing" in which a consumer sends a message to the load balancer and the load balancer sends it to the appropriate back end, in this example the load balancer can become a bottle neck on a very busy service.

An alternative is that the clients do their own load balancing by having a list of instances and choosing which ones to send it to based on reports of how busy certain instances are.

Both of these solutions have strengths and weaknesses, but a discovery service such as Eureka are required for the client side load balancing approach.

Services such as eureka often have other nice non-technical advantages, which DNS does not.

- The ability to record metadata against a service such as, which team in the company owns it, what it does.
- A central place to look up services when you are developing a new service.
- Some discovery services can track which services are looking up other services making it easy to do dependency analysis to work out what might break if a service is changed.

If the load balancer/DNS approach is working for you, a dedicated discovery service like Eureka might not fit your architecture.